# Angular form always invalid

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have an input with `ngDatePicker` and a submit button which is disabled as long as the form is not valid.

What's happening is that the form is always not valid! I've print the invalid form attribute and it's the `date` part.

I don't know why it's always giving me invalid, even tough I printed the form value after selecting the date and it have a `date` control name.

Anyone have an idea about the issue?

Here's how I'm building the form:

```
this.submitUserForm = formBuilder.group({
  email: [null, Validators.required],
  password: [null, Validators.required],
  firstName: [null, Validators.required],
  lastName: [null, Validators.required],
  date: [null, Validators.required],
  phoneNumber: [null, Validators.required],
  gender: [null, Validators.required],
  roles: [null, Validators.required]
});
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Date of birth" name="dp" ngbDatepicker
      #d_2="ngbDatepicker" formControlName="date" (click)="d_2.toggle()" [maxDate]="maxDateValue"
      onkeydown="return false" (dateSelect)="onEndDateChange($event)">
```

Comment: This seems suspect: [maxDate]="minDateValue"

Comment: Why are you using reactive forms and two way binding together ?

Comment: @vsfDawg apparently you were right. Idk why but it appear that it remain invalid even after selecting a date which is smaller than maximum date. You have any idea why?

Comment: @abhaytripathi you're right it was a mistake

Comment: @vsfDawg Please put your comment as an answer

Comment: I would suggest you to keep only ngdatepicker in form and than check . Ngdatepicker should pass data reactively to submituserform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems suspect: [maxDate]="minDateValue"

It appears that you are applying your minDateValue as the upper bound which makes reasonable input appear unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your date value is getting updated, try calling `updateValueAndValidity` method as follows.

`this.submitUserForm .get(date).updateValueAndValidity();`

This will emit the changes to all subscribers and will update the form status.

Answer (score 0):

your angular form wants the input in string as something like "yyyy-mm-dd", but the output of ngdatepicker is an object like {year: yyyy, month: mm, day:dd} that is why the form is invalid. try using ngbDateParserFormatter.format(date coming from ngdatepicker) it will format the date in string.
I hope it will work for you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).